# Ansible - Combine and Merge Lists

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am attempting to merge lists in Ansible with the final, single merged list containing no duplicate values.

My Ansible playbook is as follows:

```
- name: testing
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: set vars
      set_fact:
        paths_blah:
          - includeFilePath: "/path1"
            excludeFilePaths:
              - "/path1/aaa"
              - "/path1/bbb"
          - includeFilePath: "/path2"
            excludeFilePaths:
              - "/path2/aaa"
        paths_blob:
          - includeFilePath: "/path3"
            excludeFilePaths:
              - "/path3/aaa"
              - "/path3/bbb"
          - includeFilePath: "/path1"
            excludeFilePaths:
              - "/path1/zzz"
        paths_berry:
          - includeFilePath: "/path4"
            excludeFilePaths:
              - "/path4/aaa"
              - "/path4/bbb"
          - includeFilePath: "/path2"
            excludeFilePaths:
              - "/path1/zzz"

    - set_fact:
        paths_combined: "{{ paths_blah + paths_blob + paths_berry }}"

    - name: print vars paths_combined
      debug:
        var: paths_combined
```

When I run this playbook, the output is:

```
PLAY [print a message to screen] *****************************************************************************************************************

<snip>

TASK [print vars paths_combined] *****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "paths_combined": [
        {
            "excludeFilePaths": [
                "/path1/aaa", 
                "/path1/bbb"
            ], 
            "includeFilePath": "/path1"
        }, 
        {
            "excludeFilePaths": [
                "/path2/aaa"
            ], 
            "includeFilePath": "/path2"
        }, 
        {
            "excludeFilePaths": [
                "/path3/aaa", 
                "/path3/bbb"
            ], 
            "includeFilePath": "/path3"
        }, 
        {
            "excludeFilePaths": [
                "/path1/zzz"
            ], 
            "includeFilePath": "/path1"
        }, 
        {
            "excludeFilePaths": [
                "/path4/aaa", 
                "/path4/bbb"
            ], 
            "includeFilePath": "/path4"
        }, 
        {
            "excludeFilePaths": [
                "/path1/zzz"
            ], 
            "includeFilePath": "/path2"
        }
    ]
}
```

The **desired** output is a list with unique items merged rather than added. Taking the above lists the desired output would be:

```
paths_combined:
  - includeFilePath: "/path1"
    excludeFilePaths:
      - "/path1/aaa"
      - "/path1/bbb"
      - "/path1/zzz"
  - includeFilePath: "/path2"
    excludeFilePaths:
      - "/path2/aaa"
      - "/path2/zzz"
  - includeFilePath: "/path3"
    excludeFilePaths:
      - "/path3/aaa"
      - "/path3/bbb"
  - includeFilePath: "/path4"
    excludeFilePaths:
      - "/path4/aaa"
      - "/path4/bbb"
```

Is it possible with Ansible to perform a merge rather than, what appears to be, an append?

Comment: Hi dude0404, welcome to SO. Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, and pay especial attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section, as this is not a "write code for me" website. If you have an attempt that is not working for you, edit your question and include that attempt, along with the error that it is producing. Good luck.

Comment: Hi thanks for your welcome. I do have multiple things that i have tried however they have all failed either because they are not suitable for this structure or they are suitable but they are being misused by me. Would it be better for me to list the things i've tried and their output? My suspicion (and concern - and the reason i didn't list them) is that they are just red herrings...

Comment: @mdaniel I have largely now rewritten the question trying to take into account the advice you linked to as well as by looking at other similar questions which were well received by the community. Thank you for your patience.